# Pick JenkinsFile from custom location in pipeline plugin of jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Can jenkins pipeline plugin pick jenkinsfile from a custom location and start the build?

i don't want to keep jenkinsfile inside the source code. If there is any change in the source code. jenkinsfile from custom location should be picked and build should be started.

Example:/home/test/jenkinsfile

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reaseon why you want to do this. Maybe there is a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: I can't elaborate on the OP's motives, but we ran into this at work when we wanted Jenkins to monitor a 3rd party repo we don't control.  We could fork the repo & add a Jenkinsfile, or if there's a way to specify the Jenkinsfile contents in the job itself in Jenkins, then we could avoid forking the repo.

Comment: You can have jenkinsfile in some location and use -->load "/home/test/Jenkinsfile" . This will load the jenkinsfile from that location

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can of-course just try to put a custom location (I wouldn't see why it can't) as long as the user has rights to read the location.

If it is a multibranch pipeline, than [no](https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/). Because indexing is based the presence of a `Jenkinsfile` (only branches that contain a `Jenkinsfile` are indexed)

The thought behind having the logic of your build inside your repository is, that this is source controlled together with your sources. When you change something in your sources and this affects your build, than building that specific commit will have all the logic. If you move this outside your repository your build logic and your repository are very likely to get out of sync.

**EDIT**
You can workaround this by adding a `Jenkinsfile` that will load the other file

Jenkinsfile:

```
load "/home/test/Jenkinsfile"
```

However as far as I know, directoriees are relative to the workspace. So if you have any `dir("path/to/other/dir"){..}` than that will run relative to the workspace of the job, which makes your static `Jenkinsfile` very confusing to read.

Comment: load "/home/test/Jenkinsfile" , Worked for me!!!.   I am keeping the jenkins file outside because we use a proprietary source control , the branching works very differently there when compared to git,svn..,

Comment: In an automated pipeline integrated with a monorepo we would need to provide the directory path as input to the jenkinsfile . The directory path will be dynamic value that will change based on the project folder where the commit is made . On identifying the project folder I will need to pass folder name as variable to load Jenkinsfile from that project folder . eg : load "/home/$FolderName/Jenkinsfile" . Can someone mention a way to handle this ?

Comment: Can you evaluate the path first?

Comment: And is it possible to use multibranch project and load a Jenkinsfile from any other location?

Comment: I am not sure. Been off Jenkins for a while now. Don't know about the most recent developments. But I wouldn''t know why not. If you can access a file from within your multibranch project (put it in the definition)

Answer (score 1):

I Think there is a way.

- Once you have run your project with a regular Jenkinsfile, ...
- Make your new Jenkinsfile.other
- Go to the Jenkins Dashboard for your repository
- View the Job Configuration
- Scroll down to the `Build Configuration` section
- Change the name of your `Jenkinsfile` to your `Jenkinsfile.other`
- Run the build.

I haven't tried creating a clone Jenkins Job, and editing that one to have both always available.