# Run Jenkins file from particular folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have created new jenkins job, in which I want to execute a Jenkins file from a particular folder.

I have created one folder in my project named `pipelinescript`, in which I have placed my `Jenkinsfile`.

But when I am executing that job the file has not been detected.

In script path I have also give `/pipelinescript/Jenkinsfile`, but it is not working.

Comment: What kind of job ? Are you pulling project from a VCS (Git, Mercurial, SVN) ? Could you screen shot your Jenkins configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider:

1. Is your new job a freestyle job?  If so, you may have some trouble calling the Jenkinsfile at all.  You should be using a Pipeline job to use the Jenkinsfile approach.
2. When you define your Pipeline job, the path the to Jenkinsfile is relative to the workspace.  So to reference the Jenkinsfile in the subdirectory, you would need to configure the path like 'pipelinescript/Jenkinsfile'.  Here's a screenshot of the Pipeline job configuration form:

[image]

Comment: My project is not freestyle project. It is pipeline project. I have tried the same thing first but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mentioning /pipelinescript/Jenkinsfile please use the entire absolute path. It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all jenkins whichever files are picking up, all are workspace related. If you refer a path with no `/` in front of it, then it will load it from `workspace` only. To load a jenkins file from a custom location, you have to do like this by adding this line to the script.

```
load "/<custom path here>/Jenkinsfile"
```

For more info, please [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40441425/5003256).